# Matching/Lookup using row property from range object

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a formula in Excel VBA to parse a list of "parts" from a cell separated by commas. Lookup a cell in another worksheet with that part name, and then use the address of that cell found to get the cost of the part from the same row, different column. I've worked hours on this and thoroughly read the docs online but stuck here.

Here is the code in question:

```
Public Function PartCost() As Integer
    Dim PList() As String
    PList = Split(Cells(Application.Caller.Row, 4).Value, ", ")

    Dim element As Variant
    Dim curCell As Variant
    PartCost = 0

    For Each element In PList
        curCell = Worksheets("Parts List").Range("A1:A100").Find(element)
        PartCost = PartCost + Cells(curCell.Row, 3).Value
    Next element
End Function
```

Basically, through the use of MsgBox I've found that it does find the entry in the other "Parts List" worksheet but if I use the curCell to print out the address, row, or column I get no results.

Answer (score 2):

> `curCell = Worksheets("Parts List").Range("A1:A100").Find(element)`

is finding the cell and putting the value in the variable not the range.  You need to declare curCell as a range and then Set the variable.

```
Public Function PartCost() As Integer
Dim PList() As String
PList = Split(Cells(Application.Caller.Row, 4).Value, ", ")

Dim element As Variant
Dim curCell As Range
PartCost = 0

For Each element In PList
    Set curCell = Worksheets("Parts List").Range("A1:A100").Find(element)
    PartCost = PartCost + Cells(curCell.Row, 3).Value
Next element
```

Also if the value is not found then curcell will be nothing, you need to put a check in place to ensure the value is found.

```
Public Function PartCost() As Integer
Dim PList() As String
PList = Split(Cells(Application.Caller.Row, 4).Value, ", ")

Dim element As Variant
Dim curCell As Range
PartCost = 0

For Each element In PList
    Set curCell = Worksheets("Parts List").Range("A1:A100").Find(element)
    If Not curCell Is Nothing Then
        PartCost = PartCost + Cells(curCell.Row, 3).Value
    End If
Next element
```